Prove the collection of all function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ under some conditions is a Hilbert space.
From Conway's Functional Analysis book section 1.1 exercise 5
(A variation on Example 1.8) Let $n \geqslant 2$ and let $\mathscr{H}=$ the collection of all function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that (a) $f(0)=0$; (b) for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n-1, f^{(k)}(t)$ exists for all $t$ in $[0,1]$ and $f^{(k)}$ is continuous on [0,1]; (c) $f^{(n-1)}$ is absolutely continuous and $f^{(n)} \in L^2(0,1)$. For $f$ and $g$ in $\mathscr{H}$, define
$$
\langle f, g\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 f^{(k)}(t) \overline{g^{(k)}(t)} d t
$$
Show that $\mathscr{H}$ is a Hilbert space.
I want to prove that $\mathscr{H}$ is complete. Suppose that $f_m \in \mathscr{H}$ is a Cauchy sequence under the norm
$$||f_m||^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 |f_m^{(k)}(t)|^2 d t$$
I was hoping that the conditions would allow me to show that for fixed $x_0 \in \mathcal{H}$ I have $f_m(x_0)$ is cauchy so that by the completeness of the complex numbers it must converge to some $f(x_0)$. However all my conditions are integral conditions so this is a bit tricky.

If $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathscr H$ then $(f_n^{(k)})$ is Cauchy in $L^2(0,1)$ for all $k\leq n$, use completeness in $L^2(0,1)$.

"(A variation on Example 1.8)": of which textbook or notes? Nevermind if you remove this parenthesis.

Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sobolev+is+complete

I agree with Anne. This is the Sobolev space $H^n(0,1)$ in disguise. (It is also known as $W^{2, n}(0,1)$, etc...) @AnneBauval
